# How does empower interact with summon monster?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoning, metamagic

When a wizard prepares an empowered summon monster 3, does this affect their health?

I feel this question was asked before, but I can't find it. Sorry if it has.

Answer (score 4):

Empower boosts the spell's variables by 50% including bonuses to the die roll.

For summon monster III, the variables are 1 creature from the third level list, or 1d3 from the second level list, or 1d4+1 from the first level list.

So you would pick one of those three options, roll the die and add 50% more creatures to the amount you summon. By RAW, you would need to round down any fractions.

For example, if you elected to go with the second option, you roll 1d3, assume it came up as a 2. You would add 50% and instead summon 3 monsters from the second level list. If you rolled a 3, you would summon 4, but only because 4½ rounds down to 4.

If your choice or your dice roll says you're just going to summon 1 creature, Empower will have no effect, because your boosted 1½ creatures get rounded down to just 1.

Comment: So it has no benefit if I choose the first option?

Comment: RAW unfortunately not. You and your DM could probably find an equitable house rule that might be a good middle ground. I'm not sure what you are summoning, but see how the proposed hit points compare to those of a 5th level summon monster.

Comment: Not all metamagic will be viable options to all spells. There is no point on applying Silent on a spell without vocal component for instance.